# Dismiss or end UIScrollView

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview

I have a code I wrote that calls a UIScrollView when a button is pressed. The problem is that is remains on screen even if another button is pressed. I can't figure out how to end or dismiss this.

> (IBAction) onClickSize:(id)sender {
>
> ```
> viewSizePrint.hidden = YES;
> scrlView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1500, 214);
>
> for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
>     UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(158*i+22, 2, 154, 210)];
>     imgView.tag = i+10;
>     [scrlView addSubview:imgView];
>
>     UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
>     [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"layout%d_thumbnail", i+1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
>     btn.frame = CGRectMake(158*i+30, 10, 138, 194);
>     btn.tag = i;
>     [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickTheme:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
>     [scrlView addSubview:btn];
> }
>
> [self refreshTheme:[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].shrTheme];
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
[scrlView removeFromSuperview];
scrlView = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I had that code before and it threw an exception. Here's what it says  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
Thread 1: signal:SIGABRT